# I would like to rotate a widget using QGraphicsScene in PyQt (QLineEdit and QPushButton)

Tags: pyqt5, rotation, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicswidget

I would like to rotate a widget in pyqt5, I have developed this code but it doesn't work. The angle doesn't update and it returns a False. Do anyone know how to update this angle to make the widget rotate? If someone can help, thank you.

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

import sys

robotx=200
roboty=100

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("My Awesome Rotating Widget")
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 640, 480)

        self.R=Robot()

        self.angle=0

        self.AngleLineEdit=QLineEdit(self)
        self.AngleLineEdit.setGeometry(50,50,160,35)
        self.AngleLineEdit.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(50,50,50,20); color:black; font-weight: bold; font-size: 8pt; font-family: Helvetica; border-radius:5px;")

        self.AcceptButton=QPushButton(self)
        self.AcceptButton.setText("Accept")
        self.AcceptButton.setGeometry(50,100,160,35)
        self.AcceptButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{color:black; font-weight: bold; font-size: 8pt; font-family: Helvetica; background-color:rgb(255,255,255,20); border-radius:5px}""QPushButton:hover{background-color : rgb(255,255,255,100);}")

        container = RotatableContainer(self,self.R, 0)
        container.move(robotx,roboty)
        container.resize(150,150)
        container.setStyleSheet("background-color:transparent;")

        self.AcceptButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.RotateWidget())
        self.AcceptButton.clicked.connect(container.rotate)

        self.show()

    def RotateWidget(self):

        self.angle=int(self.AngleLineEdit.text())
        print(self.angle)


class RotatableContainer(QGraphicsView):

    def __init__(self, parent, widget, angle):

        super().__init__(parent)

        scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.setScene(scene)

        self.proxy = QGraphicsProxyWidget()
        self.proxy.setWidget(widget)
        self.proxy.setTransformOriginPoint(self.proxy.boundingRect().center())
        self.proxy.setRotation(angle)
        scene.addItem(self.proxy)

    def rotate(self, angle):

        print(angle)

        self.proxy.setRotation(angle)



class Robot(QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(0,0,100,100)        

    def paintEvent(self, event):

        p=QPainter(self)
        r=QRect(0,0,99,99)
        c=QColor(0,0,0)
        p.setBrush(QBrush(c))
        p.drawRect(r)


app = QApplication([])
window = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

I have seen an example of how to rotate a widget using a qslider but I don't know how to adapt it using a QLineEdit and a QPushButton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument of [`clicked`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) is always its check state, which by default is `False` for non checkable/checked buttons.

Since you've connected the signal to the `rotate` function, the argument is that of the button signal, and since `False` also means `0`, you're practically doing `self.proxy.setRotation(0)`.

Set the container as an instance attribute and call its `rotate` function from there:

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.container = RotatableContainer(self,self.R, 0)
        self.container.move(robotx,roboty)
        self.container.resize(150,150)
        self.container.setStyleSheet("background-color:transparent;")

        self.AcceptButton.clicked.connect(self.RotateWidget)

        self.show()

    def RotateWidget(self):

        angle = self.AngleLineEdit.text()
        if angle.isdigit():
            self.angle = angle

        self.container.rotate(self.angle)
```

<sup>Note: you should always use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html), and only classes and constants should have capitalized names (see the [Style Guide for Python Code](//python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008)).</sup>